# how to add inline style tag to "img src" statement

Tags: php, mysql, css, html

Hi how can I add style tag to this img src- eg. style=”width: 120px; height: 100px”, I tried just adding it on but if I changed or add to the statement below in any way I get errors. "Parse Errors"

```
<img src = ' . $row['image_path'] . '>
```

Comment: Check [this](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_img.asp). Also your question does not comply with SO philosofy. You need to try something on your own, and if you have problems then you post a question.

Comment: @Athafoud Check [this](http://www.w3fools.com/). [W3C](http://www.w3.org/wiki/HTML/Elements/img) should suffice

Comment: @kingkero thanks! I was aware for all the other (better) sources of informations. But I am hearing that story for the first time.

Comment: "*I tried just adding it on but if I changed or add to the statement below in any way I get errors. 'Parse Errors'*" **If you want this question to be reopened, you have to do TWO things**. 1st, **include the code** where you tried to add the size dimensions. 2nd, **include the *exact* error message**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have something like:

```
echo '<img src=' . $row['image_path'] . '>';
```

You will need quotes around the `src` value, and escape the outputted string. And add the thing you want.

```
echo '<img src="' . htmlspecialchars($row['image_path']) . '" style="width: 120px; height: 100px">';
```

Not really sure what the problems you mentioned are, the error message, a vital part of a question - is missing.

Comment: at the moment it works fine images show from the database dynamically, I tried to simply add it on to my statement but it doesnt work and page error comes up on that line, its in php. I know you can use the sizing on a normal statement with "picture.jpg" instead of .$row['image_path'].

Comment: you need to include the error, i cant guess what you're doing wrong.

Comment: Its fixed now, thanks for your help.                                <img src = ' . $row['image_path'] . ' style=" width: 120px; height: 100px; ">

Comment: why didn't you use the htmlspecialchars and quotes? It's **important**.

Comment: just for ref. it was a Parse error: parse error

Comment: then it's a syntax error. Just check your PHP syntax, easy enough. It surely even says on what line.

Comment: no good with the htmlspecialchars it gives out the Parse error with the line where the HTMLspecialchars is on

Comment: I did exactly as stated but does not work with that word in my statement, but it works fine now with out it. Cheers for help much appreciated

Answer (score 2):

First issue, your not quoting the path (src) it should be

`<img src="' . $row['image_path'] . '">`

As you have not tagged the question with CSS or HTML, only PHP and mysql, im presuming you want to use PHP to get the size of the image and insert it into the HTML.

Use [getimagesize()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.getimagesize.php)

Which returns an array with 5 elements.

- Index 0 and 1 contains respectively the width and the height of the
  image.

Note: Some formats may contain no image or may contain multiple images. In these cases, getimagesize() might not be able to properly determine the image size. getimagesize() will return zero for width and height in these cases.

- Index 2 is one of the IMAGETYPE_XXX constants indicating the type of
  the image.
- Index 3 is a text string with the correct **height="yyy" width="xxx"** string that can be used directly in an IMG tag.

You can use them values to set sizes or calculate downscaling ect

But if you just want uniformed images, set the size in the tag simply like, and dont forget the quotes:

`<img src="' . $row['image_path'] . '" width="100" height="100" >`

Comment: please re open this question or please delete it, thank you to all that replied and answered my question even though it was unclear you guys knew what i meant :)